# Modify QueryString based on ActiveStepIndex of a Wizard Control in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, wizard

I'm wondering how I could update the querystring of my URL each time I hit the Next button of a Wizard control in order to show the ActiveStepIndex.

Example:

- http ://ApplicationName/Default.aspx?Step=1
- http ://ApplicationName/Default.aspx?Step=2
- http ://ApplicationName/Default.aspx?Step=3
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Really you probably want to do this when the Active Step changes under any circumstances.

Add a handler for OnActiveStepChanged in your .aspx page:

```
    <asp:Wizard ID="NewWizard" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" OnActiveStepChanged="Wizard_OnActiveStepChanged">
    <WizardSteps>
     ...
    </WizardSteps>
   </asp:Wizard>
```

Then, implement your handler:

```
protected void Wizard_OnActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Request.QueryString.Set("Step",Convert.ToString(NewWizard.ActiveStepIndex));
}
```

This should work, however I haven't tested this code so I cannot make any kind of guarantee that it will work.

Comment: It complaints about Request.QueryString saying: "Collection is read-only."

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to handle this situation.

In HTML:

```
<body id="body" runat="server">
```

In code-behind:

```
protected void wizard_OnActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    body.Attributes.Add("onload", "document.location.hash = 'Step" + wizard.ActiveStepIndex + "';");
}
```